# Replacing 2011 Hyundai ix35 battery

Tags: battery, hyundai

Does disconnecting the battery from ix35 affect the ECU?
I want to disconnect the battery myself and have it tested by a mechanic. I wondered if disconnecting it requires extra care. I understand that without a jump start box I will lose the memory and will need to reset the radio and the clock, but can anything else also happen by disconnecting the battery without a jump start box?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing else will happen without a jump box. Make sure you don't have anything turned on when you put back your battery, because sometimes shorts happen and you might blow some fuses(no big deal), but if you can prevent it by checking your radio and headlights why not.
Edit: also fault codes get deleted.